# Show negative number as substraction result in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm coding a small program in MIPS assambler. Given my age the program do the 4 mathematical operations (addition, substraction...).

When it substract my age (29), the result should be -7 (2 - 9 = -7), but it shows 7.

How I make MIPS to show the negative number in substraction?

Thanks in advance.

```
    .globl main

    .data
mensaje:    .asciiz "Hola, mi nombre es Angel Pérez.\nHasta hace poco mi edad era 29 años.\n¿Que pasa si aplico las 4 operaciones matematicas a esos dos numeros...?\n\n"
suma:       .asciiz "2 mas 9 es igual a: "
resta:      .asciiz "2 menos 9 es igual a: "
multiplicacion: .asciiz "2 por 9 es igual a: "
division:   .asciiz "2 entre 9 es igual a: "
nueva_linea:    .asciiz "\n"
.text

main:
     la $a0, mensaje
     li $v0, 4
     syscall

     la $a0, suma
     li $v0, 4
     syscall

     li $t1, 2
     li $t2, 9

     li $v0, 1
     add $t0,$t2,$t1
     move $a0,$t0
     syscall

     la $a0, nueva_linea
     li $v0, 4
     syscall

     la $a0, resta
     li $v0, 4
     syscall

     li $v0, 1
     sub $t0,$t2,$t1
     move $a0,$t0
     syscall

     la $a0, nueva_linea
     li $v0, 4
     syscall

     la $a0, multiplicacion
     li $v0, 4
     syscall

     li $v0, 1
     mul $t0,$t2,$t1
     move $a0,$t0
     syscall

     li $v0, 10
     syscall
```

Comment: You might want to give a code sample. Make sure you have the operands in the correct order: sub res, left, right.

Comment: Sooooorry, I forgot to include a section of my code... adding it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtract order is wrong:

```
sub $t0,$t2,$t1
```

You are subtracting 9-2

```
sub $t0,$t1,$t2
```

is what you need.

Comment: I'm not substracting 9-2 but 2-9, that's why I ask how to show the negative number as result. 9-2 is 7, I want -7 that is the result for 2-9. That's what I really need.

Comment: Right, look at the order of the sub operands. You have them backward. You are doing 9-2 when you want 2-9.

Answer (score 1):

What did you expect 9-2 to return? The two operands of `sub` are inverted. The other operations also have inverted operands, but they are commutative.

Comment: I'm not substracting 9-2 but 2-9, so it's not inverted, actually, it's intended to be substracted that way.